# String Literal Escaping and Database

Tags: sql, escaping, code-injection

I have been reading up on escaping strings to avoid SQL Injection. I do understand that parameterized queries are the safest way to avoid Injection. 
But i do have a question regarding Escaping as means of complimenting Parameterized queries.

Suppose the input field **"Name"** had the value **O'Brian** and was escaped using the below routine:

```
sSanitizedInput = "'" & Replace(sInput, "'", "''") & "'"
```

So the value now looks like **O''Brian**. If this were to be inserted in the database using the Insert query, will the inserted value be actually **O''BRIAN**?

If that is the case, then in order to search the name column for the inserted value O''Brian, will i have to escape it to O''Brian before executing the Select query to match it with the value inserted in the DB?

Comment: if you are using parametized queries, the database will store the value of the parameter, so if the param value is O'Brian it will store O'Brian if you change it to O''Brian then it will store O''Brian.  It would be pretty easy for you to just try and see the result I think.

Comment: What database are you using? I assume it’s SQL Server.

Comment: Yes its SQL Server 2012